# Keep formatting of chart when pasting into PowerPoint

Tags: vba, excel, excel-charts

I've used the following function to make and format my chart.

```
Function CreateTwoValuesPie(ByVal x As Long, ByVal Y As Long) As Chart
Set CreateTwoValuesPie = charts.Add
  CreateTwoValuesPie.ChartType = XlChartType.xlDoughnut
  With CreateTwoValuesPie.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Values = Array(x, Y)
  End With
  With CreateTwoValuesPie
    .ChartGroups(1).DoughnutHoleSize = 20
    .ChartArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    .Legend.Delete
  End With

End Function
```

I'm trying to copy my chart into a PowerPoint slide, but it looks like that the formatting of the size of the hole is not copied as well. I'm using the following code to create, copy and paste my chart into powerpoint.

```
Set oPPTShape10 = oPPTFile.Slides(1)
'EarlyAdoption
d11 = Format(Dashboard.EAScore1.Caption, "Standard")
Set ch = CreateTwoValuesPie(d11, 10 - d11)

With ch
.CopyPicture _
Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
End With

With oPPTShape10.Shapes.Paste
.Top = 200
.Left = 200
.Width = 300
End With
```

The code gives me the following chart in PowerPoint.
[PowerPoint Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63xE1.png)

This does clearly not have the hole size 20 as I'm trying to. How do I fix the format of the chart when copying to PowerPoint? Thanks!

Comment: What about storing the dimensions (width & height) of chart and apply them to the shape on the slide?

Comment: The problem is not the dimension but the formatting of the chart itself. I've added it though.